# Only show changed files while syncing from ext4 to NTFS

Tags: rsync

I would like rsync to print modified and deleted files. The verbose option (-v) does print modified files but also the list of subdirectories, maybe because touched directories are considered modified. Since I sync a lot of files from a lot of subdirectories, it's impossible to see the actual changes.

So, is there a way to not print directories using rsync ?

Im not looking for `grep -v "*/$"` kind of answers since it would also exclude new directories.

Command I am using: `rsync -avh --delete /media/data/src /media/data/bkp`

And everytime it prints the list of all directories:

```
src/dir1/

src/dir1/sdir1/

src/dir1/sdir2/

src/dir2/
```

---

EDIT: Ok, after some intensive tests .. It doesn't print all directories when syncing from an ext4 partition to an ext4 and from NTFS to NTFS. It only does when syncing from ext4 to NTFS .. And options `-c` or `--omit-dir-times` don't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a permission issue. Not sure why ..
But I've edited /etc/fstab for NTFS partitions and it now works as expected, ie no printing of directories that haven't been modified.

Old fstab entry: 
ntfs-3g users,defaults,exec,uid=1000    0   0

New fstab entry:
ntfs-3g users,defaults,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=077,fmask=137   0   0

Im guessing (who knows ..) dmask=077 did the trick ie 'drwx---' instead of 'drwxrwx'.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using `--omit-dir-times` switch to ignore directory times (take a look at rsync man page).

I personally find that using `-c` switch is the best way to ensure that only the files whose contents has been changed show up in the output.

Note that using `-c` will slow down rsync.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I find hard to believe it's not natively supported, at least without losing perfomance (or options) .. I'll just have to trust it syncs it all.

Comment: Sorry, my edit changed the question after your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the mount type you can also tell rsync to ignore file permissions when copying to a filesystem that doesn't support it. The following command works for me.

From the rsync man page:

> In  summary: to give destination files (both old and new) the source permissions, use --perms.  To give new files the destination-default permissions (while leaving existing files unchanged), make sure that the  --perms  option is  off and use --chmod=ugo=rwX (which ensures that all non-masked bits get enabled).  If you’d care to make this latter behavior easier to type, you could define a popt alias for it, such as  putting  this  line  in  the  file ~/.popt  (the  following  defines  the -Z option, and includes --no-g to use the default group of the destination dir):

```
rsync alias -Z --no-p --no-g --chmod=ugo=rwX
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use -a, it contain -p -o -g.

Comment: You can still use `-a` if you want, and then add `--no-o --no-p --no-g` to omit owner, group and permissions.

Answer (score -1):

I used:

```
sudo rsync -auzhni --progress --omit-dir-times --no-o  src_dir/ dst_dir
```

It is a dry run (option `n`). Remove that option in order to have `rsync` actually transfer files.